# Non negative matrix factorisation in python on individual images

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, nmf

I am trying to apply NMF to a particular image that is loaded in grayscale mode. I have tried several links but my image after application of NMF remains almost the same and cannot be distinguished with the grayscale image initially loaded.

However, when i come across the scikit-learn's code on implementing decomposition on a dataset, i see that the faces there have been transformed into ghost - like faces. Here is the link:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_faces_decomposition.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-decomposition-plot-faces-decomposition-py

And here is the code I am using:

```
import cv2    
from sklearn import decomposition    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

img = cv2.imread('test1.jpeg',0)    
estimator = decomposition.NMF(n_components = 2, init = 'nndsvda', tol = 5e-3)    
estimator.fit(img)    
vmax = max(img.max(), -img.min())    
plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation = 'nearest',vmin=-vmax,vmax=vmax)    
plt.show()
```

I am new to the techniques of NMF on matrices espicially such a large image numpy array.
My image is test1.jpeg that is 225 * 224 .jpeg image.

Can someone please help me on implementing the code for a single image?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason  you get the original image in the plot is that you actually plot the original image. Instead you would need to work with the output of `estimator`.

The NMF decomposition produces two matrices `W` and `H` that compose the original matrix. You need to multiply those to get the image.

```
import cv2    
from sklearn import decomposition    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np   

img = cv2.imread('data/trump2.jpg',0)  
vmax = max(img.max(), -img.min())

fig, (ax, ax2)  =plt.subplots(ncols=2)    
ax.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation = 'nearest',vmin=-vmax,vmax=vmax)

n_components = 20

estimator = decomposition.NMF(n_components = n_components, init = 'random', tol=5e-3)    
W = estimator.fit_transform(img)
H = estimator.components_

new_img = np.dot(W,H)
ax2.imshow(new_img, cmap=plt.cm.gray,
                   interpolation='nearest',
                   vmin=-vmax, vmax=vmax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help sir!